# resteasy enable strict parsing with mime4j

Tags: resteasy, mime4j

is there a way to set mime4j strict parsing to true for resteasy without hacking into and extending MultipartFormDataInputImpl? according to [mime4j 0.8 javadoc](https://james.apache.org/mime4j/apidocs/org/apache/james/mime4j/stream/MimeConfig.html#setStrictParsing(boolean)), the default value is false. we want to have it throw an exception rather than having a warn as what default gives

> public void setStrictParsing(boolean strictParsing)
>
> Defines whether minor violations of the MIME specification should be tolerated or
> should result in a MimeException. If this parameter is set to true, a
> strict interpretation of the MIME specification will be enforced, If
> this parameter is set to false minor violations will result in a
> warning in the log.

Comment: It doesn't look like that is an option currently. You could file a feature request at https://issues.redhat.com/browse/RESTEASY though.

Comment: thanks. our legacy code did it by overriding the source code which makes upgrade a nightmare. i guess i will have it as it.

Comment: Ah bummer. I don't really see an easy way to override it either with the way it's written. However, that seems like a reasonable request.